# How to change default sort order in Catalina's Reminders?

Tags: catalina, reminders

The new Reminders with Catalina allows the user to change the sort order, but does not remember the user's choice after system restart and always defaults to Apple's choice, which I believe is manual. Is there any way to change the *default* sort order to, say, due date, which would be my preference? I cannot find a suitable .plist file where default sort order is a parameter that can be changed. Any hints or ideas welcome.

Comment: Since sort order is not a preference but only a menu action I doubt that it is stored somewhere

Answer (score 1):

I am inclined to accept the comment by @Joakim Danielson as the answer. Accordingly, instead of expecting a solution in a .plist file, I have written this Applescript to execute on startup (you also have to grant it accessibility permissions in Security & Privacy)

```
tell application "Reminders"
    activate
end tell
#wait for Reminders to launch since can't control startup items order
do shell script "/bin/sleep 5"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Reminders"
        tell menu bar 1
            tell menu bar item "View"
                tell menu "View"
                    tell menu item "Sort By"
                        tell menu "Sort By"
                            click menu item "Due Date"
                        end tell
                    end tell
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```